# datalab SSH key ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-datalab

Recently when I try to connect to my datalab VM from cloud shell, i see the following error even if I am Project Owner:

> Connecting to datalab-vm1-1.
>   This will create an SSH tunnel and may prompt you to create an rsa key pair. To manage these keys, see https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys
>   Waiting for Datalab to be reachable at http://localhost:8081/
>   Permission denied (publickey).
>   ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
>   Connection broken
>   Attempting to reconnect...

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be something similar to https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/1936

That only occurs on old VMs, so try creating a new datalab VM with the latest version of gcloud (which Cloud Shell should have by default).